# Avro Array is actually a List

Tags: java, arrays, list, maven, avro

I use .avsc data with a maven plugin to create Java classes.
But when I wanted to create an instance of this object and set the values in my constructor, the defined arrays are interpretated as a List of values.

My example:

```
{"type": "record", "name": "test", "namespace": "testing",
"fields": [
    {"name": "id", "type": ["null", "int"]},
    {"name": "arr", "type": ["null", {"type": "array", "items": "double"}]}
]
}
```

Now 
`test t = new test(1, new double[]{1.0,2.0,3.0})` says it needs `java.util.List<java.lang.Double>`.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: can you show your constructor to clarify the definition of it?

Comment: in this case its this code generated by the avro:schema plugin:

     public particle(java.lang.Integer id, java.util.List<java.lang.Double> arr,)
      {
     this.id = id;
     this.arr = arr;
      }

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass in a `List<Double>` rather than an array of `double` as that's what the `Test` constructor expects.

if you don't intend to modify the list then you can use [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)):

```
test t = new test(1, Arrays.asList(1.0,2.0,3.0));
```

However, if you intend to modify the list then you'll need to construct an object of type `List` then pass it into the constructor.

```
List<Double> tempList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1.0,2.0,3.0));
test t = new test(1, tempList);
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much. 

It works for now, but can you explain why avro does this, instead of intializing the variable as an array?

Comment: @thejoeka to be honest, I've actually never used _avro_ before but one thing for sure is your constructor has defined it expects a _List<Double>_ and this is completely different to an _array of double_. Also, to answer your question _instead of initializing the variable as an array?_, it did create your double array but it didn't work because again you've provided the wrong type.